# Adding a link to a specific row

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm trying to add an image to a specific row. I have numerous of images that I'm trying to add to a table and this Google image keeps popping up in every row instead of just one. I have a snippet of the code where I'm adding the image and the parameters for each row. I was trying to add the image by doing {{link.img}} like the website, URL, and description but that didn't work either. Below is a snippet of the code that has a screenshot of what's printing out. I would like to get {{link.img}} working if possible so I can be consistent with all the other parameters, but if that's not feasible that's fine. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eXeA.png)

```
LINKS = [
    {
        'id': uuid.uuid4().hex,
        'img': "../assets/ipts.png",
    },
    {
        'id': uuid.uuid4().hex,
        'img': "../assets/express.png",
    }
]


<table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col"></th>
              <th scope="col">Website</th>
              <th scope="col">URL</th>
              <th scope="col">Description</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(link, index) in links" :key="index">
              <!--<td>{{ link.img }}</td>-->
              <td>
                  <img v-bind:src="link.img" width="21" height="21">
                  <img src = "../assets/google-logo.png" width="21" height="21">
              </td>
              <!--<td><a href="{ link.URL }">{{ link.website }} </a></td>-->
              <td>{{ link.website }}</td>
              <td>{{ link.URL }}</td>
              <td>{{ link.description }}</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like this is working fine it just can't find your images. Can you confirm that the images you want for `link.img` are in the assets folder?

Answer (score -1):

Use the object data keys without qoute sign as follows :

'id'=> id and ........

```
links = [
    {
        id: uuid.uuid4().hex,
        img: "../assets/ipts.png",
    },
    {
        id: uuid.uuid4().hex,
        img: "../assets/express.png",
    }
]
```

Comment: Having single quotes or not still allows access to the string `link.id`, if they had `img-link` that would need to be in single quotes

Comment: Make sure that the image src URL works well, I recommend you use alias name instead of relative URL in Vue to prevent the same problems

Comment: I have other parameters inside of here like description and website with the single quotes around them and they work fine, its just the image. I did what you suggested however the image still appears as in the image above.